# finding clusters in a network from eigengaps

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modules, clustering

I have a usual Laplacian matrix, which describes a network. From the matrix I get the eigenvalues and from these I can compute a metric of modularity in my network based on the largest eigengap. Let's say that the largest eigengap is at eigenvalue (rank) #5, suggesting that there are 5 modules in my network. Is there a way to discover which nodes constitute each module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Suppose $k$ is the number of clusters, which correspond to low eigenvalues. Let $L$ be the Laplacian, let $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ be the eigenvectors corresponding to the $k$ small eigenvalues, and $V$ be the $n \times k$ matrix whose columns are $v_1, \ldots, v_k$. There are $n$ rows of $V$ corresponding to the $n$ elements of the graph (network). The standard way to determine the clusters (modules) is to use the $k$-means clustering algorithm on the rows of $V$. Then for each cluster $C$, take the elements of the graph corresponding to the rows of $V$ in $C$.

Note that $k$ can't necessarily be easily determined from the largest eigenvalue gap - there's quite a bit of subtlety in inferring $k$.

[Here](http://web.mit.edu/~wingated/www/introductions/tutorial_on_spectral_clustering.pdf) is an introduction of spectral clustering with several variants of the above algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. As a follow-up: at this point in my analysis, the eigenvalues are ranked, so how can I relate the cluster of eigenvalues to the original nodes of the network?

Comment: Let the nodes be $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ according to their rows/columns in the Laplacian matrix. Then node $x_i$ corresponds to the $i$th components of the eigenvectors, or equivalently, row $i$ of $V$ (as defined above). When you cluster $V$, you will get clusters consisting of groups of rows of $V$. If a cluster contains rows $i_1, \ldots, i_t$ then the corresponding cluster of nodes is $x_{i_1}, \ldots, x_{i_t}$.